# Difference between renderer and session methods in ARKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I checked the following two sample codes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor])
{  
    for anchor in anchors        
    {            
        guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor else { continue }
        let skeleton = bodyAnchor.skeleton
    }
}
```

and: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
{
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }
    let blendShapes = faceAnchor.blendShapes    
}
```

The code to extract the BlendShape of the face uses "renderer" to get the value of the BlendShape.

However, the code that detects body movement uses "session" to get the value.

Both of the two codes seem to be for getting values that are updated from ARAnchor.

What's the difference between "renderer" and "session"?

How do I use the two codes at different times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)`  and `session(_:didUpdate:)` instance methods update AR content (camera/model position or some specific data like face expressions) at 60 fps. They work almost identically but they have different purposes. For five `renderer(...)` instance methods you have to implement [ARSCNViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate) protocol. For four `session(...)` instance methods you have to implement [ARSessionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate) protocol.

An official documentation says:

> ARSCNViewDelegate's methods provide the automatic synchronization of SceneKit content with an AR session. And ARSessionDelegate's  methods work directly with ARFrame objects.

### The main difference is:

- you must use `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)` instance method for ARKit+SceneKit copula, because it works with ARSCNView object.
- also, you can use `session(_:didUpdate:)` method for ARKit+SceneKit copula, because it also works with ARSCNView object.
- and you must use `session(_:didUpdate:)` method for ARKit+RealityKit copula, because it works with ARView object.

Comment: can I use both? will it causing any threading issue?

Comment: Which scenario would force you to use both methods at the same time?

Comment: I my project, the `renderer` is used to detect the floor , and the `session' to handle all other AR stuffs. I'm not too sure it's correct way of doing that

Comment: Sorry @HaiHw, what do you mean saying "other AR stuff" ?

Comment: such as adding new SCNNode, show animation, handle interaction

Comment: You can use all this stuff inside `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)` and `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)`. There's no need to use `session(...) methods`.

Comment: This is the issue that I'm trying to fix. Could you take a look, thanks in advanced. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67224698/ios-renderer-thread-deadlock-com-apple-scenekit-scnview-renderer-thread-stuck-a

Comment: Are you using both methods in your app (`session()` and `renderer()`) ?

Comment: There's insufficient info in your question. What's the size of your SCNScene in polygons (10K, 100K, 1M)? What's the size of textures – 1Kx1K, 2Kx2K, 4Kx4K ? How much dynamics and animations your does scene contain? Etc...

Comment: Try to use only `renderer(...)` methods, and if the issue is still there – give additional info about you scene, models and textures.

Comment: you think app freezes because of resources are too big or system overloaded, don't you? <br> 
I think it's no the case, somehow the renderer thread is locked, but I don't know how to track what trigger that lock. <br>
one reason I need to use `session()` is to get the `capturedImage` from `ARFrame`

Comment: All factors are important. The size of a model (in polys) and the size of textures (in pixels) are the most important two!

Comment: A normal working scene size must be not greater than 50K polygons (100K maximum), a size of every texture – not greater than 1K x 1K pixels (2K x 2K maximum).

Comment: A scene containing 500K of polys or greater is unacceptable.