# ARKit – Renderer thread deadlock

Tags: ios, thread-safety, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

My AR iOS App just hangs during the ARSession without any clue of the issue, or what blocking the main thread 
Any help is really appreciated.
Below is the threads backtrace

```
(lldb) thread list
Process 83660 stopped
  thread #1: tid = 0xa7210c, 0x00000001d8e02784 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_rw_wrlock + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #6: tid = 0xa721c0, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread'
  thread #10: tid = 0xa721e2, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'AVAudioSession Notify Thread'
  thread #11: tid = 0xa72247, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader'
  thread #13: tid = 0xa722cc, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient'
  thread #26: tid = 0xa723b3, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread'
  thread #31: tid = 0xa723f8, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.arkit.ardisplaylink.0x28057aa00'
* thread #32: tid = 0xa723f9, 0x00000001d8e03290 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ulock_wait + 8, name = 'com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer', queue = 'com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.ARSCNView0x11391c2f0'
  thread #37: tid = 0xa72477, 0x00000001f56d486c libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread
  thread #38: tid = 0xa72484, 0x00000001f56d486c libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread
  thread #40: tid = 0xa725a1, 0x00000001f56d486c libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread
  thread #43: tid = 0xa725ae, 0x00000001d8e0348c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
(lldb) thread info
thread #32: tid = 0xa723f9, 0x00000001d8e03290 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ulock_wait + 8, name = 'com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer', queue = 'com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.ARSCNView0x11391c2f0'

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #32, name = 'com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer', queue = 'com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.ARSCNView0x11391c2f0'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001d8e03290 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ulock_wait + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000112429fcc libdispatch.dylib`_dlock_wait + 52
    frame #2: 0x000000011242a348 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_group_wait_slow + 56
    frame #3: 0x00000001dedcd120 SceneKit`-[SCNTextureCoreAnimationSource _resizeLayer:toSize:updateLayer:updateTransform:caRenderer:] + 204
    frame #4: 0x00000001dedcd6c4 SceneKit`-[SCNTextureCoreAnimationSource __renderLayerUsingMetal:withCARenderer:engineContext:viewport:atTime:forceUpdate:didUpdate:] + 216
    frame #5: 0x00000001dedcde40 SceneKit`-[SCNTextureCoreAnimationSource __updateTextureWithLayer:texture:engineContext:sampler:] + 804
    frame #6: 0x00000001dedce404 SceneKit`-[SCNTextureCoreAnimationSource metalTextureWithEngineContext:textureSampler:nextFrameTime:] + 372
    frame #7: 0x00000001defea5d4 SceneKit`kSCNTextureSourceCallbackGetMetalTexture + 60
    frame #8: 0x00000001dee2664c SceneKit`-[SCNMTLResourceManager(Textures) renderResourceForImageProxy:sampler:engineContext:] + 200
    frame #9: 0x00000001dee2652c SceneKit`-[SCNMTLResourceManager(Textures) renderResourcesForEffectSlot:withEngineContext:] + 128
    frame #10: 0x00000001dee48e38 SceneKit`__39+[SCNMTLRenderContext registerBindings]_block_invoke_28 + 80
    frame #11: 0x00000001dee46270 SceneKit`_execute(SCNMTLRenderContext*, DrawCommand) + 4316
    frame #12: 0x00000001dee45034 SceneKit`-[SCNMTLRenderContext drawRenderElement:withPass:] + 600
    frame #13: 0x00000001dee43fa4 SceneKit`-[SCNMTLRenderContext processRendererElements:count:engineIterationContext:] + 932
    frame #14: 0x00000001def6da78 SceneKit`C3D::DrawNodesPass::_renderEye(long) + 508
    frame #15: 0x00000001def6d7c8 SceneKit`C3D::DrawNodesPass::execute(C3D::RenderArgs const&) + 196
    frame #16: 0x00000001def74bd8 SceneKit`C3D::ScenePass::execute(C3D::RenderArgs const&) + 252
    frame #17: 0x00000001dedff644 SceneKit`C3D::__renderSlice(C3D::RenderGraph*, C3D::RenderPass*, unsigned short&, C3D::RenderGraph::GraphNode const&, C3D::RenderGraph::Stage*&, C3D::RenderArgs, bool, id<MTLCommandBuffer>&) + 1672
    frame #18: 0x00000001dee00e30 SceneKit`C3D::RenderGraph::execute() + 4660
    frame #19: 0x00000001deef8f20 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _renderSceneWithEngineContext:sceneTime:] + 440
    frame #20: 0x00000001deef9788 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawSceneWithNewRenderer:] + 272
    frame #21: 0x00000001deef9cfc SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawScene:] + 48
    frame #22: 0x00000001deefa0a4 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawAtTime:] + 636
    frame #23: 0x00000001def95418 SceneKit`-[SCNView _drawAtTime:] + 452
    frame #24: 0x00000001dee5a2f0 SceneKit`__76-[NSObject(SCN_DisplayLinkExtensions) SCN_setupDisplayLinkWithQueue:screen:]_block_invoke + 56
    frame #25: 0x00000001def60e14 SceneKit`__36-[SCNDisplayLink _callbackWithTime:]_block_invoke + 64
    frame #26: 0x0000000112429528 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #27: 0x0000000112438740 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 124
    frame #28: 0x00000001def60da4 SceneKit`-[SCNDisplayLink _callbackWithTime:] + 232
    frame #29: 0x00000001b0079640 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 660
    frame #30: 0x00000001b014ba20 QuartzCore`display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 276
    frame #31: 0x00000001ace9eb54 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 172
    frame #32: 0x00000001acec2420 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    frame #33: 0x00000001acec1834 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 588
    frame #34: 0x00000001acebb9f4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2332
    frame #35: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #36: 0x00000001ae0da7f8 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
    frame #37: 0x00000001dee5a7d8 SceneKit`__78-[SCNView(SCNDisplayLink) _initializeDisplayLinkWithScreen:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 668
    frame #38: 0x00000001dee5aa74 SceneKit`__SCNRenderThread_start__ + 96
    frame #39: 0x00000001f56cfc9c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 288
(lldb) thread info
thread #31: tid = 0xa723f8, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.arkit.ardisplaylink.0x28057aa00'

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #31, name = 'com.apple.arkit.ardisplaylink.0x28057aa00'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001d8ddea48 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 72
    frame #2: 0x00000001acec10fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
    frame #3: 0x00000001acebb570 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1176
    frame #4: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #5: 0x00000001acebbc60 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRun + 60
    frame #6: 0x00000001d6bca270 ARKitCore`-[ARRunLoop _startThread] + 560
    frame #7: 0x00000001ae2374bc Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 848
    frame #8: 0x00000001f56cfc9c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 288
(lldb) thread info
thread #6: tid = 0xa721c0, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread'

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #6, name = 'com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001d8ddea48 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 72
    frame #2: 0x00000001acec10fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
    frame #3: 0x00000001acebb570 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1176
    frame #4: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #5: 0x00000001ae0da7f8 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
    frame #6: 0x00000001ae0da6d8 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
    frame #7: 0x00000001af858054 UIKitCore`-[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 504
    frame #8: 0x00000001ae2374bc Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 848
    frame #9: 0x00000001f56cfc9c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 288
(lldb) thread info
thread #10: tid = 0xa721e2, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'AVAudioSession Notify Thread'

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #10, name = 'AVAudioSession Notify Thread'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001d8ddea48 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 72
    frame #2: 0x00000001acec10fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
    frame #3: 0x00000001acebb570 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1176
    frame #4: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #5: 0x00000001b443b098 AudioSession`GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156
    frame #6: 0x00000001b443cff8 AudioSession`CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 88
    frame #7: 0x00000001f56cfc9c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 288
(lldb) thread info
thread #11: tid = 0xa72247, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader'

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #11, name = 'com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001d8ddea48 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 72
    frame #2: 0x00000001acec10fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
    frame #3: 0x00000001acebb570 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1176
    frame #4: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #5: 0x00000001ad74c4b0 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol11132$$CFNetwork + 552
    frame #6: 0x00000001ae2374bc Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 848
    frame #7: 0x00000001f56cfc9c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 288
(lldb) thread info
thread #13: tid = 0xa722cc, 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient'

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #13, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001d8ddea48 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 72
    frame #2: 0x00000001acec10fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
    frame #3: 0x00000001acebb570 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1176
    frame #4: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #5: 0x00000001b59334e0 AudioToolbox`GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156
    frame #6: 0x00000001c19ec464 libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib`CADeprecated::CAPThread::Entry(CADeprecated::CAPThread*) + 88
    frame #7: 0x00000001f56cfc9c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 288
(lldb) thread info
thread backtrace
* thread #26, name = 'com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001d8ddf644 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001d8ddea48 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 72
    frame #2: 0x00000001acec10fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
    frame #3: 0x00000001acebb570 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1176
    frame #4: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #5: 0x00000001acebbc60 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRun + 60
    frame #6: 0x00000001b7914d68 CoreMotion`___lldb_unnamed_symbol6249$$CoreMotion + 1308
    frame #7: 0x00000001f56cfc9c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 288
(lldb) thread backtrace
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #38
  * frame #0: 0x00000001f56d486c libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread
(lldb) thread info
thread #1: tid = 0xa7210c, 0x00000001d8e02784 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_rw_wrlock + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread'

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread'
    frame #0: 0x00000001d8e02784 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_rw_wrlock + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001f56cec98 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_rwlock_lock_wait + 84
    frame #2: 0x00000001f56cec20 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_rwlock_lock_slow$VARIANT$armv81 + 676
    frame #3: 0x00000001defcc23c SceneKit`C3DTransactionFlush + 444
    frame #4: 0x00000001acec087c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    frame #5: 0x00000001acebaf50 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 604
    frame #6: 0x00000001acebb498 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 960
    frame #7: 0x00000001acebaba0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #8: 0x00000001c3c20598 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
    frame #9: 0x00000001af7ac2f4 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 1052
  * frame #10: 0x00000001af7b1874 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 164
    frame #11: 0x0000000104389cb8 verifyt-b2c-app`main at AppDelegate.swift:14:7 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x00000001acb99568 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple SCNBox instead 3D model in your scene – and you'll see whether a number of polygons and texture size spawn this freeze. If yes, for AR app prepare a scene containing not greater than [100K polygons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_visual_effects_in_ar_quick_look_and_realitykit) (ideally, not greater than 50K polygons) and `png`/`jpg` textures for models not greater than 2Kx2K in size (ideally, not greater than 1Kx1K).

If the reason of freeze isn't a mentioned one – try to use just `renderer(...)` methods, instead of `renderer(...)` and `session(...)` together.